# how to add row after interval into database SQL using spring boot at midnight 12:01 am

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a bus booking project,
I don't know to apply this date shifting.
My requirement is that

If today people booked 25 tickets out of 30. so the next day all seats should be empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement this use case. I prefer this one, create a domain that has a field of date, a field of maxSeat, and it can hold a list of userIds. So every day when someone requests for taking a seat, you can retrieve data by date, and if there is no instance for that particular date you can create one, and put that user's id into the userIdList, with that manner you can modify your maxSeat and if you'll need any other extra field or operation, you can handle them.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Or if you are persisting in doing that in your way, you can search about scheduling tasks with spring boot, so that can help you to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Dear. I am not asking this.
I want to know how to create new row with maxbusSeat fields after interval.